# Call web api in docker network between container with two docker compose

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose, docker-network

How can I make a request from one docker container to another using the docker network and two different docker-compose files which contain the container settings?

I've a simple web api that should be called using this console application. The web api is hosted using the following docker compose file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  webapi_test:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapi_test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: webapi_test/Dockerfile    
    links:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - sample_network
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
    networks:
      - sample_network

networks:
  sample_network:
    name: sample_network
```

The web api should be called using this simple console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var url = "https://webapi_test:44334/api/Role";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var result = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;

        Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
    }
}
```

Docker compose of the console application:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  networksample:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}networksample
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NetworkSample/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - sample_network

networks:
  simplic_network:
    name: sample_network
```

The communication should be done in the local docker network as far as I know. But I always get the following error message in the console application: `SocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable` The web api is available from outside: `https://localhost:44334/api/Role`...

**EDIT** I just have one docker host.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a SSL issue, try to replace `https` with `http` in `var url = "https://webapi_test:44334/api/Role";`

Comment: Should I need to change the port than? Because `44334` is by `https` port: `- "44334:443"`

Comment: @BendEg oh! try first `https://webapi_test:443/api/Role`; when connecting within the network, use exposed port, not published.

Answer (score 1):

make `sample_network` as external network:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  networksample:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}networksample
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NetworkSample/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - sample_network

networks:
  simplic_network:
    external:
       name: sample_network
```